# Is it possible for chat.js "Stepped Line Chart" to render the stepped line without the next data point

Tags: chart.js

[image]
The stepped line currently works as shown above.

The illustrations below aim to emulate the 'steppedLine: "before"' option.

```
            o
o----       |
    |       |
    |   o----
    |   |   
    o----

1   2   3   4   5   6
```

If datapoint 4 would be missing the line graph would be drawn as shown below

```
o----
    |
    |   o
    |   |   
    o----

1   2   3   4   5   6
```

Is it possible to have it drawn this way instead?

```
o----
    |   
    |   o----
    |   |
    o----

1   2   3   4   5   6
```

---

*For my application (in which I am using this represenation to indicate x users making use of a specific service per y time) visually it would make more sense to me to have the line drawn up to (but not including) x=4.*

*With a step between mesurements we assume the value remains sort of the same or they can only increment in whole numbers.
The graph however (to me) does not really clearly show this.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw your own line directly on to the canvas using the [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api) together with [`CanvasRenderingContext2D`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D). It offers different hooks that may be used for executing custom code. In below code snippet, I use the `afterDraw` hook to draw a dashed horizontal line from the last data point up to the the position of the next tick.

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), {
  type: 'line',
  plugins: [{
    afterDraw: chart => {
      var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
      var xAxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
      var yAxis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'];
      var dataset = chart.config.data.datasets[0];
      var data = dataset.data;
      var xFrom = xAxis.getPixelForTick(data.length - 1);
      var xTo = xAxis.getPixelForTick(data.length);
      var y = yAxis.getPixelForValue(data[data.length - 1]);
      ctx.save();
      ctx.strokeStyle = dataset.borderColor;
      ctx.lineWidth = dataset.lineWidth;
      ctx.setLineDash([8, 4]);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(xFrom, y);
      ctx.lineTo(xTo, y);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }],
  data: {
    labels: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "My Dataset",
      data: [5, 1, 3],
      borderColor: 'red',
      lineWidth: 3,
      steppedLine: 'before', 
      fill: false
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          stepSize: 1
        }
      }],
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.js'></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="90"></canvas>
```

Comment: Excellent! Thx this works! Would it be possible for you to modify your awnser to also include the background color of the bar being rendered? I forgot to add it in the question :(

Comment: @Dex: If you mean the legend label, i just updated the code and show it now.

Comment: No sorry I ment that if you remove the option "fill: false" the background under the lines are filled, that color i'd like for the extra line as well. I was able to add a ctx.fillRect but the height of the rectangle is still invalid. y is too heigh as it overflows the x-as as well

Comment: I think I got it: ```
     ctx.save()
     ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(111, 170, 77, 0.3)"
     ctx.fillRect(xFrom, y, xTo-xFrom, xAxis.bottom - xAxis.height - y)
     ctx.restore()```